# django how to serialize fields into DateTimeRangeField

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm having a bit of trouble serializing fields into DateTimeRangeField.  The request currently has to have the following format:

```
data = {"time":
         {
           "lower": timeThing,
           "upper": laterTimeThing
         }
       }
```

What I would like it to look like on the request is this:

```
data = {
           "start": timeThing,
           "end": laterTimeThing
       }
```

So I can then serialize start/end into lower/upper.
Here is my model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    time = DateTimeRangeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('user.User')

class ExampleAPI(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = Example.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time = DateTimeRangeField(write_only=True)
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        exclude = ['user']
```

I've tried creating a [custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#a-basic-custom-field) but it doesn't seem to go into the overriden to_representation or to_internal_value.  The error message I got was {'time': ['This field is required.']}

Answer (score 4):

You can try `DateRangeField` from [drf-extra-fields](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields):

```
pip install drf-extra-fields
```

Then:

```
import datetime

from rest_framework import serializers
from drf_extra_fields.fields import DateRangeField


class RangeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ranges = DateRangeField()


serializer = RangeSerializer(data={'ranges': {'lower': datetime.date(2015, 1, 1), 'upper': datetime.date(2015, 2, 1)}})
```